# linux ubuntu not recognizing my new ssd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd

I just installed a new Samsung ssd onto my linux ubuntu computer, but when I go to settings and to about, it only shows my 1Tb hard drive, not my 480 gb ssd

Comment: How is your SSD connected to your computer (which interface)?

Comment: Disconnect hard drive and Reconnect that again and immediately run "dmesg" command to see if device recognized or not. Is your hard drive cable correct ? Also try the following command :
ls -l /dev/sd* | grep sd

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to partition it first, using a partitioning tool such as `gparted`. If your partitioning tool of choice does not automatically format the new partition(s), you will then need to format then, using e.g. `mkfs`. **Be careful not to repartition/reformat the wrong device!**